# How to implement multi-level delegate in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I have 4 classes (views):
A, B, C and D

Class A calls B, B calls C, and C Calls D: 
A > B > C > D

In class D I have implemented a delegate protocol and I want to catch the delegate event in class A.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are multiple ways how you could achieve this. What's best in your case depends on the situation. Here are some ideas:

1. You could implement the delegate protocol in all of those classes and simply pass it down the line.
2. You could add an ivar to access class D from A and pass it directly (danger of [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)!)
3. If it's possible you could change your implementation, so that you only implement the delegate in A and handle it right there.
4. A last resort could be using `NSNotifications` (not to be confused with `NSUserNotifications` in Mountain Lion). In your class A you post a notification to the default notification center and in class D you register to this notification and handle it as you want. Only use this approach though if nothing else works, because this can result in even worse code.

Comment: +1 for showing multiple methods and explaining why some are better.

Answer (score 0):

**Assign ClassD member delegate as  ClassA object.**

Let me explain

If you have a UITableView in ClassD and want to trigger the ClassD tableView Delegates in ClassA, let assign the tableView delegate as ClassA object and implement all the UITableView delegates in ClassA.

Eg: `ClassD_tableView.delegate = classAObj;`

Note: Implement the  ClassD tableView delegate methods in Class A and Do not create a new object of ClassA from inside ClassD. you can get the parent Class A in ClassD through passing the parameter or using UIResponder.